# Why is the Bluetooth SPP UUID reserved in Android >2.2?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working on an Android Application that
communicates with another device via bluetooth.

It opens a Bluetooth Server Socket with
the well-known standard UUID for SPP communication:
(00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB).

But since the Android 2.2 update on my Archos Tablet this fails with an exception,
saying that this UUID is reserved.

On a Milestone with Android 2.1 the same code works without problems.

Why is this UUID reserved?
In the Android Source I can see the Array of reserved UUIDs, but the SPP ID is not included.

see: http://grepcode.com/file/repository....RESERVED_UUIDS

Does anybody know a workaround that would enable opening a bluetooth socket with the given UUID?

The exception stacktrace from the log:

```
W/BluetoothService( 1290): Attempted to register a reserved UUID: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
E/BluetoothService(20201): Socket listen() failed
E/BluetoothService(20201): java.io.IOException: Not able to register SDP record for GlucoTel SPP
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfco mmWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:778)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at com.bodytel.android.BluetoothService$AcceptThread. <init>(BluetoothService.java:285)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at com.bodytel.android.BluetoothService.start(Bluetoo thService.java:156)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at com.bodytel.android.BodytelAndroidClient.onResume( BodytelAndroidClient.java:246)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(I nstrumentation.java:1149)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3 823)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(A ctivityThread.java:3118)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(Ac tivityThread.java:3143)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Ac tivityThread.java:2684)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThr ead.java:125)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Activit yThread.java:2033)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99 )
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.jav a:4627)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit .java:626)
E/BluetoothService(20201): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Android Java Code Snippet we use to open the bluetooth socket:

```
private static final String BT_NAME = "GlucoTel SPP";
private static final UUID BT_ID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
.....
BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothServerSocket socket = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BT_NAM E, BT_ID);
.....
socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

We have observed this issue on the following devices:

**Test Device 1:**
- Archos 32
- Firmware 2.1.8 (Android 2.2.1)
- Board Version: A32-V5

**Test Device 2:**
- Archos 101
- Firmware 2.0.54 (Android 2.2.1)
- Board Version A101IT-V6

Thanks for any ideas or feedback!

Comment: Is it possible that some application is already using / registering with thus UUID ?

Comment: Yes this is one possible scenario, but how can we find out which service/application is running? In the bluetooth API I cannot find a call that would retrieve this information.

Comment: try querying using the SDP tool from a remote linux machine

Comment: Just thought I'd say, in case it's any use, that I'm able to run a Bluetooth application that uses the same SPP UUID on my own Archos 101 running Android 2.2 without any problem. I'd be interested to know why you're having this problem on your own Archos 101. Did you come to a solution?

Comment: @StefanKostopoulos: Have you resolved the issue, if yes, plz put it as an answer, so that others, including me can benefit.

Thank You